# If I restart sql server agent 2005 will the database go down too?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Or will everything else, such as database access, work as far as apps and users are concerned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database server will stay up, but any executing jobs will be killed.